# How is the universe flat?

Tags: cosmology, spacetime, universe, curvature, cosmological-inflation

I have real trouble visualising what is meant by the descriptor 'flat' when referred to the shape of the observable universe. Which one of the below is more accurate?

a) It is flat in a 2D way, like a big disk mostly spread out on one plane, similar to a solar system or disk-shaped galaxy

b) It is flat in a 3D way, in the sense that lines in space travel straight and even in all directions, e.g. like the lines of a gridded cube

c) It is not like either of the above, but something else all together

BONUS QUESTION: if the closest and most simple explanation is b), then what would be a better term than 'flat', which suggests 2 dimensionality to general audiences?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably learned Pythagoras' theorem at school, and this states that if you move a distance $x$ along the $x$ axis then $y$ along the $y$ axis the distance between your starting and ending points is given by:

$$ s^2 = x^2 + y^2 \tag{1} $$

If we extend this to three directions by including motion along the $z$ axis then we get:

$$ s^2 = x^2 + y^2 + z^2 \tag{2} $$

What your teacher didn't tell you is that this is only true when the space is flat. For example if you try (the 2D version of) this experiment moving on the surface of a sphere then you'll find that:

$$ s^2 \lt x^2 + y^2 $$

When we say the universe is flat we mean that for any three displacements $x$, $y$ and $z$ equation (2) correctly gives the distance between the starting and ending points.

Incidentally, space**time** is not flat. When we say the universe is flat we mean that if we take a moment in time, i.e. a spatial hypersurface, then equation (2) applies.

Comment: Why do you say this _"...if we take a moment in time...."_ John?

Comment: How do you define "$x$" and "$y$" on a sphere? It doesn't have coordinate axes.

Comment: Thanks John. So if you had to choose between a) and b) in the original question to explain to lay audiences, would it be b)? And do you think the term 'flat' is misleading?

Comment: @Amphibio: I suppose (b) is not a bad way of explaining it in the sense that we can fill the universe with a regular array of identical cubes. Just bear in mind that the size of these cubes changes with time (as the universe expands). Yes, the word *flat* is misleading. Physicists often use common words in a technical way that can confuse non-physicists.

Comment: @Sidarth: if **spacetime** were flat the universe wouldn't be expanding (or contracting). Spacetime is curved, but we can choose our time axis so that if we take the 3D submanifold $(t=\text{const}, x, y, z)$ for some constant value of $t$ then the submanifold has a Euclidean metric (which is what we mean by flat).