# Measuring the Hubble constant in a curved universe

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, spacetime, space-expansion, curvature

In an [article](https://scitechdaily.com/fresh-twist-to-debate-over-universes-age-from-new-view-of-the-oldest-light-in-the-universe/) from the University of Chicago, July 17, 2020, it is stated that

> "Judging cosmic distances from Earth is hard.  So instead, scientists measure the angle in the sky between two distant objects, with Earth and the two objects forming a cosmic triangle.  If scientists also know the physical separation between those objects, they can use high school geometry to estimate the distance of the objects from Earth."

That seems straightforward, except for the fact that high school geometry only works in flat space where the angles enclosed by a triangle add up to precisely 180 degrees.  In a curved universe, a triangle can enclose either more or less than 180 degrees.  Unless the curvature is known, triangulation shouldn't work reliably in a curved space.

So my question is: in measurements of the Hubble Constant by the triangulation method, what assumptions are made about curvature of the universe?  And, how well-founded are those assumptions?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedmann%E2%80%93Lema%C3%AEtre%E2%80%93Robertson%E2%80%93Walker_metric and  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda-CDM_model

Comment: That link contains a lot of interesting information, but does not seem to contain an answer to my specific question.

Comment: How so? You asked about assumptions about curvature of the universe  and especially the first link contains them (homogenity and isotropy)  together with the general form of the metric possessing these symmetries and resulting field equations. The second link then elaborates on field equations themselves.

Comment: Perhaps I've missed something, but it seems that assuming homogeneity and isotropy does not restrict curvature other than to say that the curvature is the same everywhere.  My question is about how curvature affects interpretation of results when measuring the Hubble constant.  I get the impression that, usually, space is assumed to be flat (have zero curvature).

Comment: @S.McCrew "homogeneity and isotropy does not restrict curvature other than ..." It is pretty strong restriction though. The spatial geometry is given up to one constant (and scale/expansion function).. "usually, space is assumed to be flat" because it is. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shape_of_the_universe.

Comment: @S.McCrew Not to mislead you, due to expansion of the universe I am not sure if you can use high school formula for triangulation even if space is indeed flat.

Comment: Agreed.  Taken to the extreme, two points ~13 billion light years distant from Earth and seen in opposite directions from the Earth would have been less than one billion light years apart a short while after the Big Bang, not the roughly 19 billion light years that straightforward Euclidean geometry would indicate.

Comment: @S.McCrew I do not understand your argument. How do you do the triangulation? There is no triangle in your example....However, because of the homogeneity and isotropy of universe, the observed angle between two objects might actually remain the same all the time (triangles preserves their angles during expansion, but the triangle we are observing is not spatial as it takes time for light to travel). If so. from knowledge of distance of the two objects at certain time and angle now, you could use trigonometry to compute distance from Earth at the particular time.

Comment: Let's say we can see object A by looking straight North, and it's 10 billion LY away.  And we can see object B by looking straight South, also 10 billion LY away.  In a non-expanding universe that means the two objects are 20 billion LY apart.     But in an expanding universe 10 billion LY in diameter *now*, the light from objects we see 10 billion LY away was emitted when expansion began, when the objects were very close to each other.

Comment: The distance measurement you describe is called "parallax" and is only possible to do for relatively nearby celestial objects. It can be used to help calibrate methods for measuring farther objects, but other than that, cannot help in determining the Hubble Constant.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are looking for angular diamater distance. For different curvature the equation takes different forms. See here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_diameter_distance

Answer (score 0):

What appears to be a sufficient answer to the question can be found in this [SE answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/239509/how-is-the-universe-flat) by @JohnRennie, combined with a few other articles.  I had confused "flat space" with "flat spacetime".  As John Rennie said in that answer, spacetime is not flat in an expanding universe, but *space* can be flat. So, indeed, it is necessary to account for the expansion of space when measuring the Hubble constant via triangulation.

The [link given by @Layla](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_diameter_distance) provides the formula used to relate distance, physical separation, and angular separation, and space curvature. The formula is based on the FLRW model, described in [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedmann%E2%80%93Lema%C3%AEtre%E2%80%93Robertson%E2%80%93Walker_metric) provided by @Umaxo This [NASA article](https://lambda.gsfc.nasa.gov/education/graphic_history/hubb_const.cfm) outlines the discrepancies between results obtained by different measurement methods.

Various approaches are taken to measure the curvature of space (*space*, not spacetime), including [this article](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.3847/1538-4357/ab5f61) which describes a method using gravitational lensing.

So, the answer is this: generally, when calculating the Hubble constant it is assumed that the universe is spatially flat but expanding at a rate that may change over time.  The assumption of spatial flatness is well-founded, at least to a close approximation, on several types of astronomical observations.